# iptables -L shows only one source IP

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I've added multiple IPs to iptables:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 1.1.1.1,...,99.99.99.99 -j DROP
```

iptables-save shows them all:

```
-A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1/32 -j DROP
...
-A INPUT -s 99.99.99.99/32 -j DROP
```

But iptables -L shows only the last one:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  99.99.99.99        anywhere
```

Why is that? Can iptables output be made more informative and list all added IPS?

Comment: Comma separated sources are converted to different records. Please provide full output of ``iptables -L -n``. I bet there should be your rules.

Comment: Indeed, `-n` works, thank you. It seems that I tried it but with wrong table. If you wish to provide this as the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: ``-n`` is not for table, it is for not to resolve addresses to domain names using PTR/reverse zone. Without of ``-n`` your ``99.99.99.99`` may become ``dnsr4.sbcglobal.net`` )

Comment: I used it with -t as well, so there was wrong table. Thanks, good to know.